# Extract hyper-cubical blocks from a numpy array with unknown number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a bit of python code which currently is hard-wired with two-dimensional arrays as follows:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(5, 5)
width = 3

for y in range(0, data.shape[1] - W + 1):
    for x in range(0, data.shape[0] - W + 1):
        block = data[x:x+W, y:y+W]
        # Do something with this block
```

Now, this is hard coded for a 2-dimensional array and I would like to extend this to 3D and 4D arrays. I could, of course, write more functions for other dimensions but I was wondering if there is a python/numpy trick to generate these sub-blocks without having to replicate this function for multidimensional data.

Comment: `ndim` will give you the number of dimensions. If you construct your code to iterate over `range(arr.ndim)`, then you'll repeat whatever you're doing for the number of dimensions in the array

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the comment. The issue with that is that I could not figure out how to construct these blocks which will also have `ndim` dimensions. Now that I write this, perhaps list comprehension may be a way to do this....

Comment: I usually find that if I'm iterating over a `numpy` array, there's almost always a better solution that uses `numpy` more efficiently

Comment: yeah, trying my best here. if I crack it, I will update :)

Comment: It looks like you have a 5x5 array and you are gathering all of the 3x3 arrays inside of it.  Are you asking: if you had a 5x5x5, how to gather all of the 3x3x3 arrays?  Or: how to gather all of the 3x3 for each of the 5 layers?  In other words, should the gathered data have the same dimension as the input data?

Comment: @James Yes, that is correct. Except I do not want to write code for each `number of dimension` array that I have. Currently I am trying to see if I can use numpy ndindex to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my wack at this problem.  The idea behind the code below is to find the "starting indices" for each slice of data. So for 4x4x4 sub-arrays of a 5x5x5 array, the starting indices would be `(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,1)`, and the slices along each dimension would be of length 4.

To get the sub-arrays, you just need to iterate over the different tuples of slice objects and pass them to the array.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

def iterslice(data_shape, width):
    # check for invalid width
    assert(all(sh>=width for sh in data_shape), 
           'all axes lengths must be at least equal to width')

    # gather all allowed starting indices for the data shape
    start_indices = [range(sh-width+1) for sh in data_shape]

    # create tuples of all allowed starting indices
    start_coords = product(*start_indices)

    # iterate over tuples of slice objects that have the same dimension
    # as data_shape, to be passed to the vector
    for start_coord in start_coords:
        yield tuple(slice(coord, coord+width) for coord in start_coord)

# create 5x5x5 array
arr = np.arange(0,5**3).reshape(5,5,5)

# create the data slice tuple iterator for 3x3x3 sub-arrays
data_slices = iterslice(arr.shape, 3)

# the sub-arrays are a list of 3x3x3 arrays, in this case
sub_arrays = [arr[ds] for ds in data_slices]
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I came to a very similar solution like yours but could not get it to really work. Particularly, did not know that the `slice` function existed!